# Android Testing: Appium not working

Tags: android, testing, automated-tests, appium, selendroid

I have installed Appium for Windows (Appium version 1_4_16_1). But when I double click on it to start, I get an error:

> Appium Stopped Working, windows is checking a solution to the problem.

My system specifications are: Windows 8.1, 64 bit OS, 4GB RAM.  I have implemented these steps, please let me know if I am missing something.

[image: screenshot]

1. Installed JDK 1.8 and Android SDK 2.0.
2. Set up the environment variables.
3. Installed node js.
4. Installed Appium version 1_4_16_1.

Comment: This error shows that the appium itself failed to start. (Crashed etc). I would suggest uninstalling and installing a fresh copy of appium currently.

Comment: I tried it but it is not working..

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue with (Appium version 1_4_16_1), after a lot of troubleshooting found that i am facing this issue only in this particular version of Appium. Try uninstalling this version and Install Appium Version 1_4_13_1. It works fine.

Comment: I have already tried Appium version 1_4_13_1 and 1_4_0_0 but facing the same issue.